# Confused with the difference between HTML entity code and the raw

Tags: javascript, html

Code([jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rgrrha5y/)):

```
<script>
function f(input) {
    return '<article>' + input + '</article>';
}     
document.write(f('<script>alert(1)<\/script>')); //alert 1
document.write(f('&lt;script&gt;alert(1)&lt;\/script&gt')); // write normal text
</script>
```

In my idea, `<script>alert(1)<\/script>` is the same as `&lt;script&gt;alert(1)&lt;\/script&gt`(the raw vs http entity codes), but it results different result, could any body explain about that?

Comment: The first line write actually html. The second line write text that **seems like** html. (Try to edit this node in Chrome (Find this element in`Elements` -> Right click -> Edit as HTML) and you will see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're not the same. `<` is the actual `<` character, which in HTML is the beginning of a tag. `&lt;` is the HTML named character entity we use for `<` when we want to actually have a `<` in the text, which we can't otherwise do because...it starts a tag.

So `<script>` is the beginning of a `script` tag, whereas `&lt;script&gt;` is how we put the characters `<`, `s`, `c`, `r`, `i`, `p`, `t`, `>` in the HTML.

Forget about `document.write` and `script` tags, just look at HTML itself:

This:

```html
<div>Testing 1 2 3</div>
```

...is the markup for a `div` element containing the text `Testing 1 2 3`.

In contrast, *this*:

```html
&lt;div>Testing 1 2 3&lt;/div>
```

...is the markup for the `<` character (as text) followed by `div>Testing 1 2 3` followed by another `<` character (as text) followed by `/div>`.

Answer (score 2):

The first line

```
document.write(f('<script>alert(1)<\/script>'));
```

adds actual HTML into the `<article>` element. You can see the alert get executed.

The second line

```
document.write(f('&lt;script&gt;alert(1)&lt;\/script&gt'));
```

adds text to `<article>`, which you can see on screen, but nothing is executed.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, That's `HTML Entity` instead of `Http Entity`,
and it will be parsed as code immediately when browser read the `<script>alert(1)<\/script>`.

For this reason, we need to prevent that browser read them as code, we hope browser treat them as words, like characters, so people write the `HTML Entity` to display special characters, then browser will treat them as html text (becasuse they are characters and symbols).

For more info, you could ref to http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm, there is a table of HTML entity code, hope it will help you.